# Masstransit Problem adding Payload to request/response in Unit Testing, alternativly using Pipes in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, masstransit

currently I have the problem that I want to write unit tests for Masstransit in .NET. My request/response consumer has some consumer filters, one of these filters are generating extra data as message payload and attaching this to the request message. In order to test my consumer in a unit test I would like to add the Payload.

Q1) Is it possible to add the payload to the request message
Q2) Alternativly, can I make a mocking filter and set it as consumer filter in the pipeline? (Which sets the payload)

This is my latest attempt:

```
    public class ContactCommandConsumerTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task CreateContactOnUserRequestConsumer_RequestConsumer_IsAttached()
        {
            var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness { TestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };

[...]


            var consumer = harness.Consumer<CreateContactOnUserRequestCommandConsumer>(() => new CreateContactOnUserRequestCommandConsumer(loggerConsumer, mapper,kontakteintragRep,machineTime));
            var pipe = Pipe.New<PipeContext>(x => x.UseFilter(new MockFilter<PipeContext>()));


            // harness.Consumer<CreateContactOnUserRequestCommandConsumer>();
            await harness.Start();

            

            try
            {
                harness.Bus.ConnectConsumePipe<CreateContactOnUserRequestCommandConsumer>(pipe);

                var requestClient = await harness.ConnectRequestClient<CreateContactOnUserRequestCommand>();

                var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<AcceptedResponse, FaultedResponse>(new
                {
                    EntityInfo = "Vb48cc135-4593-4b96-bb29-2cf136b3d1ee",

                });


                Assert.True(consumer.Consumed.Select<CreateContactOnUserRequestCommand>().Any());
                Assert.True(harness.Sent.Select<FaultedResponse>().Any());


            }
            finally
            {
                await harness.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class MockFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T: class, PipeContext
    {
        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
            context.CreateFilterScope("mock");
        }

        public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
        {
            context.GetOrAddPayload(() => new ContextUserPayload() { ContextUser = new Guid("dc6e091f-669e-45b3-9dd6-a36316f70527") });
            await next.Send(context);
        }
    }
```

I tried to build a pipe and add it to "harness.bus.ConnectConsumerPipe". But the mock filter is never called ???

Answer (score 0):

You use use the `OnConfigureInMemoryBus` event on the `InMemoryTestHarness` to add your filter to the bus endpoint.

Similar to:

```csharp
harness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += configurator =>
{
    configurator.UseFilter(...);
}
```

To add a filter to the request, use:

```csharp
using RequestHandle<TRequest> requestHandle = requestClient.Create(message, cancellationToken);

requestHandle.UseFilter(...);

return await requestHandle.GetResponse<TResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The solution is still not touching my filter. DI:
            services.AddMediator(x =>
                {
                    x.ConfigureMediator((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ContextUserFilter<>),context);
                    });

Try
            harness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += conf =>
            {
                conf.UseFilter<PipeContext>(new MockFilter<ConsumeContext<PipeContext>>());
            };
--> No filter called
                conf.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MockFilter<>), ???);

Comment: Your generic types are all wrong, you should be [using this extension method](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Configuration/MessagePipeConfiguratorExtensions.cs#L16) to add your filter, where `T` is your message type.

Comment: I was on the wrong track, now it is working, using .harness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += conf => { conf.UseFilter<CommandX>(new MockFilter<ConsumeContext<CommandX>>()); } Thank you for your help. BTW: Thank you also for developing MassTransit, saves us a lot of time