# Middleware testing in MassTransit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, masstransit

I am trying to unit test some filters I've created as part of a POC in MassTransit.

I was wondering how this is normally done. There are some examples that show the whole Filter pipeline configured. I was hoping to test just the filters with no actual consumer wired up.

Something like this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66697737/1727038

I could mock out the entire context but I wondered if mock contexts already existed?

I feel like testing with a consumer aswell means it's not really a Unit test of the filter functionality but more the filter and consumer combined.